# Why AOP is not working in my Spring Boot project? It never execute the @Around annoted method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I was trying to follow this video tutorial to add **AOP** to my Spring Boot project in order to perform log operation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVvKPP5HyaA

But it is not working, it is not logging anything.

So this is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.easydefi</groupId>
    <artifactId>GET-USER-WS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GET-USER-WS</name>
    <description>Microservice that retrieves users from DB</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        
        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.martijndwars</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-push</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
          <version>1.68</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
     

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see I added this dependency to it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I created this **LoggingAOP** class in order to configure AOP behavior:

```
package com.easydefi.aop.logging;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@Aspect
@Component
@Log
public class LoggingAOP {
    
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.easydefi.users.*.*.*(..))")
    public void myPointcut() {
        
    }
    
    @Around("myPointcut()")
    public Object applicationLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        String className = pjp.getTarget().getClass().toString();
        
        Object[] argsArray = pjp.getArgs();
        
        log.info("Method invoked " + className + ":" + methodName + "() arguments: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(argsArray));
        
        Object response = pjp.proceed();
        
        log.info(className + ":" + methodName + "() Response: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
        
        return response;
        
    }

}
```

In theory the used **@Pointcut** expression:

```
@Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.easydefi.users.*.*.*(..))")
```

should define the execution o all method into all class of all package defined into the project root that is **com.easydefi.users** but it is logging nothing.

Running my application and calling a controller method or a service method I expected that he would enter into the **applicationLogger()** method. But it is not working (I also tried in debug mode and it never enter into this method).

This is my project structure:

[image]

So what is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: Your project inherits from `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.5.6` but you included dependency `spring-boot-starter-aop:2.6.3`. You would typically omit the version and let Spring Boot dependency management bring in the appropriate version of the starter.

Comment: The expression doesn't mean what you think it means. Instead you should be writing something like `execution(* com.easydefi.users..*(..))`, which does mean all methods inside the package and subpackages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointcut

```
execution(* com.easydefi.users.*.*.*(..))
```

looks a bit unflexible, but it works perfectly for intercepting methods like

```
public void com.easydefi.users.service.CoinService.doSomething()
public boolean com.easydefi.users.specification.MySpec.fooBar(int, String)
```

It works not for

```
public String com.easydefi.users.specification.criteria.MyCriteria.zot()
public void com.easydefi.users.aa.bb.cc.SomeService.zot()
```

for reasons ***M. Deinum*** has mentioned already. His suggestion to use the `..*` notation, which means "any method in any class in the package preceded by `..*`", is exactly right:

```
execution(* com.easydefi.users..*(..))
```

I also want to stress that the credit for this answer should be his, and if he likes to simply copy my answer and post it under his own name instead of just a comment, I shall remove this one gladly instead. But I do think questions deserve comprehensive answers.